# Maintaining checkbox value on local Storage React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to save the value of checkboxes in local storage, so when the user reloads the page, they remain checked/unchecked.
I have an "isChecked" state and a handleOnChange function.

What im trying to do is store the value on the state, and every time the onChange fuction runs, i set the 'checkbox' key on local storage to the value of the checkbox.

this is what my component looks like

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Pdf = (props) => {
  const [shown, setShown] = useState(false);

  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(localStorage.getItem('checkbox') === 'true');

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
      setIsChecked(localStorage.getItem('checkbox'));
      localStorage.setItem('checkbox',`${e.target.checked}`)
  }
  

  const toggle = () => {
    setShown((prevState) => !prevState);
    alert(isChecked)
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="pdfContainer  row container justify-content-center">
      <section className="justify-content-center">
        <h1 className="row justify-content-center h1--style">
          Κεφάλαιο {props.id}
        </h1>
        <p className="row justify-content-center p--style">{props.info}</p>
      </section>
      <button onClick={toggle} className=" shadow button--style">
        Μάθημα {props.id}
      </button>
      {shown && <embed className=" pdf" src={props.pdf} />}

      <div className="pdfChecked input-group-text input-group ">
        <input 
            type="checkbox"
            id='pdfchecked'
            name="pdfChecked" 
            value='1'
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            /> <label className="input--label"> Διάβασα το κεφάλαιο!</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pdf;
```

I understand that this is very buggy, and very much not how you're supposed to do it. I found the local storage concept hard to grasp as a beginner, and i have tried many ways to make this work. As of now, it *kinda* works, meaning when i reload the page it stays the same, but i have to click on the checkbox multiple times! SO buggy. Any help, especially letting me know why my thought process is wrong, would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `handleOnChange` look strange. Why are you setting isChecked to whatever is in local storage, then after that updating the local storage with the value you got from the event? Just use the event value for both. As an idea for practicing. Turn this into a custom hook, and make use of `JSON.stringify/parse` to keep track of the data types for you automatically (strings, numbers, booleans).